# Lua: extending userdata in metatables

Tags: lua, metatable, lua-userdata

I am trying to find a proper solution for some protected employee userData that I want extend with additional entries/data for easy access

Here's a rough example of what I'm trying to do:
*This works, but I dont like that I have to put all the custom logic inside the index function*

```
setmetatable(self, {
    __index = function(t,k)
        if k == "isDriving" then --custom data
            return user.inCar and user.onRoad
        elseif k == "isLateToWork" then --custom data
            return user.wokeUpLate and user.startTime < user.arrivalTime
        else
            return user[k] --original userData
        end
    end
})
```

and how I access the custom data:

```
print(employee.isDriving)
```

Ideally I would want to put the custom logic in a separate function, like the example below:
*This doesnt work, can also not pass an argument (returns nil)...*

```
if k == "isDriving" then --custom data
    return self:IsDriving(t) --t holds carData and roadData
```

How can I solve this problem? Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self:IsDriving(t)` is sugar for `self.IsDriving(self,t)`.

So, the first time the index metamethod is called with `k` equal to `IsDriving`, create a function that does what you want, `rawset` it to `IsDriving`, and return it.

However, it's simply easier to create a plain method called `IsDriving` in the first place.

Comment: totally forgot about that syntactic sugar stuff :(